# Jasmine:How to pass event data along with triggerEventHandler

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running unit test for angular, I want to pass event data along with click event.
I want to pass this number along with click event. I call the function load() when I click on the button and I print if I received the event data, but I don't see nothing printed

```
 let ButtonDOM = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#loadbtn'));
 console.log(ButtonDOM.nativeElement);// able to print dom element
 ButtonDOM.triggerEventHandler('click',{number:2564});

 function load(){
 console.log(number);//nothing printed
 }
```

**template.html**

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="name">Customer Number</label>
   <input type="text" id="accountid" class="form-control col-sm-3" [(ngModel)]="record.accountid" (change)="daemonChanged(0)" name="accountid" required>
   <button id="loadbtn" (click)="loadCustomer()" class="col-sm-3 btn">Load</button>
 </div>
```

the above code snippet seems not to be working, I want number to be passed when I click the function.

Comment: WHat is the HTML code ?? Can you please share that as well  ? The `number` should be passed from `HTML` expression itself , right ?

Comment: Thanks  Shashank , I have edited my question included html part as well, To set the textContent, I have added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113017/how-to-set-text-content-of-html-input-element-in-unit-test