# How to set text content of html input element in unit test

Tags: html, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am running unit test for angular app, I want to set the text content of this input element via unit test.I am using jasmine

```
<input type="text" id="accountid" class="form-control col-sm-3" [(ngModel)]="record.accountid" name="accountid" required>
```

I tried this but it is not working

```
let formData = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#accountid'));
formData.nativeElement.value = 22;
fixture.detectChanges();
console.log(formData.nativeElement.textContent);//expected to print 22
expect(formData.nativeElement.textContent).toBe(22);//fails
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must dispatch an `input` event after setting the value of it:

```
let formData = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#accountid'));
    formData.nativeElement.value = 22;
    formData.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

expect(formData.nativeElement.value).toBe(22);
```

Comment: Thanks Chrillewoodz, but this didn't set the text content of input element, tried fixture.detectchanges after every statement, didn't work

Comment: @karansys I don't think you should be testing for `textContent`, but rather the value.

Comment: Thanks :) that works , can you edit your answer, so I will mark it as correct